# Separate defintions, lemmas proofs from the body of a book?

Tags: shorthands

as you know in latex it is possible to create a list of shortcuts (like formulas) and call that inside the body of a document/book. I was wandering if it is possible to do a similar stuff with definitions/lemma/proofs. Like to say... create a file with all proofs, label them and when i refer the label just substitute to the label the body of the proofs.

Would that be possible?

I will use the following example to explain what i would like to achieve:

```
\begin{definition}
We define the set of normalized floating point numbers $\FloatingPointSet{e}{t}$ as
\begin{equation}
    \FloatingPointSet{e}{t} = \left\{x \in \mathbb{R} \; : \; 
        \left\{
        \begin{array}{l}
            x = (-1)^{s_x} 2^{e_x} 1.m_x, \\
            s_x \in {0,1} \\
            2 - 2^{e - 1} \leq e_x \leq 2^{e-1}-1 \\
            1.m_x = \sum_{i=0}^{t} x_{-j} 2^{-j} \\
            x_0 = 1
        \end{array}
        \right.
        \right\}.
    \label{eq:floatingPointSetDef}
\end{equation}
    \label{def:floatingPointSetDef}
\end{definition}
\begin{proposition}
    For each $x \in \FloatingPointSet{e}{t}$ we can write
    \begin{equation}
        x = (-1)^{s_x} 2^{e_x - t} M_x,
        \label{eq:floatingPointIntegerSignificand}
    \end{equation}
    where $2^t \leq M_x \leq 2^{t+1} - 1$
\end{proposition}
\begin{proof}
\begin{multline}
    x = (-1)^{s_x} 2^{e_x} 1.m_x = (-1)^{s_x} 2^{e_x} \sum_{i=0}^{t} x_{-j}2^{-j} = \\ 
    (-1)^{s_x} 2^{e_x-t} \sum_{i=0}^{t} x_{-j}2^{t-j} = (-1)^{s_x} 2^{e_x-t} M_x
\end{multline}
where $M_x$ is defined as
\begin{equation}
    M_x = \sum_{i=0}^{t}x_{-j}2^{t-j}
\end{equation}
since $x_0 = 1$ then $2^t \leq M_x$, so $2^t$ is the lower bound, for the upper bound we just put $x_{-j} = 1 \;\; \forall j = 1 \ldots t$ so the upper bound is $2^{t+1} - 1$.
\end{proof}
\begin{definition}
    For each $x \in \FloatingPointSet{e}{t}$ we define
    \begin{equation}
        \text{ulp}\left( x \right) = 2^{e_x - t}
    \end{equation}
\end{definition}
```

My idea was...

put this stuff on a single file like:

```
\begin{defintion}
 %text def
 \label{def1}
\end{definition}

\begin{lemma}
  %text lemma
  \label{lemma1}
\end{lemma}

\begin{proof}
  %text def
  \label{proof1}
\end{proof}
```

In a single file... then in the real body of the document (in a different file) i'd like to be able to do something like:

```
The following defintion is useful and summarizes what we explained so far
\ref{def1},
it is easy to see that the following lemma holds
\ref{lemma1}
\ref{proof1}
```

So actually i would like to avoid to put all the proofs in a single file together with the text of the document, because it make me confusing when i have to dig the document in order to find an error. Would that be possible?

Comment: Something like a `glossary` of proofs? Possible, I think, but we need more information how the proofs etc. are typeset, i.e. a working frame!

Comment: I created an example, no i'm not looking for a glossary but literally some kind to reference a proofs for text subistitution (i.e. a kind of macro substitution). In the body of the book i would like to reference something, and when i compile there should be a text substitution. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: The `glossary` was perhaps misleading, but one could define glossary entries with keys which are your shorthands then. There's no need to include the glossary at the end (or whereever) at all

Comment: Could you make an example please?

Comment: I'll try later on